# Why deserializing does not convert a JSON string to struct or array in Coldfusion?

Tags: arrays, json, serialization, coldfusion, struct

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string in `Coldfusion8`. It seems to work (no errors), but I'm not able to work with the data I'm getting.

My JSON string looks like this:

```
"{\"kundenliste\":{\"kundennummer\":\"1\",\"plz\":\"2\",\"rabatt\":\"3\",\"laenderkennzeichen\":\"4\",\"preisliste\":\"5\...
```

I can do this:

```
<cfset variables.import = DeserializeJSON(getModus.myJSONstring)>
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#IsArray(variables.import)#">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#IsStruct(variables.import)#">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#IsObject(variables.import)#">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#IsDefined(variables.import.kundenliste)#">
```

Results in:

```
{"kundenliste":{"kundennummer":"1","plz":"2","rabatt":"3","laenderkennzeich ...
NO
NO
NO
<<error>>
```

**Question**:
Am I doing something wrong when deserializing? I thought this would return a struct or array and not a string. What to do?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The original JSON string looks invalid. The quotes should not be escaped like that ie `\"`. The input should look more like your "result". What is the source of that string?

Comment: hm. I think I constructed it myself. One second

Comment: ok. If I un-backslash, I have a `struct`. Hm. I wonder why I stored it like this in the first place... Thanks! Make it answer?

Comment: Not much of answer .. but okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original JSON string is invalid. The quotes around the name/value pairs should not be escaped like that ie `\"`, which is why it is not being parsed properly.  The input string should look more like your "result":

```
    {"kundenliste":{"kundennummer":"1"}}
```

What is the source of that string?